# How do I change a value for a Fabric.js object?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a Fabric.js `canvas`. I also have a javascript that has a function that gets called when a button is pressed. I know how to get the active object, `canvas.getActiveObject()`, but i don't know how to just change a value in it without having to make a clone and deleting the original. The reason why i just want to change the original is because when the button is pressed again, weird things happen. Any clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 9):

There are many getters and setters for values:

```
object.setWidth(val);
object.setHeight(val);
object.setStrokeWidth(val);
object.setLeft(val);
object.setTop(val);
```

You can also change values with general set method:

```
object.set('width', value);
object.set({ width: value, height: value});
```

If you change dimension or position affecting properties you have to call `object.setCoords()` after changing the property. Otherwise the "click area" of the object is wrong.
After changing properties you have to call `canvas.renderAll()` to re-render all objects.

For more information just have a look at the docs: [fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html)

Comment: These setters are no longer inside the docs you refer to. I also tried `setStrokeWidth` and the method seems to be non existent. Is this answer outdated? What version of the library are you referring too?

Comment: @Wilt this.canvas.getActiveObject().toObject().name = properties.Name; This code is not working for me. Would you explain whats my mistake. I'm using the FabricJS version 4.3.1

Answer (score 3):

Apparently setters are removed in the latest version of Fabric.js (using version 2.7.0). You can now simply set the properties on the object directly:

```
// Set your new property values
object.width = val;
object.height = val;
object.strokeWidth = val;
object.left = val;
object.top = val;

// Then you mark the object as "dirty" and render the canvas:
object.dirty = true;
canvas.renderAll();
```

Alternatively you can set all properties at once using the `set` method an object like this:

```
// Set all properties at once using the set method
object.set({ 
    width: val, 
    height: val,
    strokeWidth: val,
    left: val,
    top: val
});

// In this case the setter marks the object as "dirty" so you only need to call renderAll
canvas.renderAll();
```