# How to update Javascript Variables from HTML input in real time?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm making a program whereby rectangles can be modified in realtime (depending on what the user keyboard input is) using fabric.js.

I'm having an awful time doing this.

I'm trying to get the input `id=width` and input `id=height` to be able to edit the rect.width and the rect.height and PREFERABLY have it change the shape of the rectangle as I'm doing it.

I've included my code below, I've just removed all my attempts at         `document.getElementById('height').value;` because they have all been absolutely useless, and when I include them it breaks the whole script (which I didn't think was very useful for a jsfiddle).

I think I'm in a bit over my head.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7kmw6h8/4/)

HTML

```
<body>
  <input id="width" type="number" value="100"> <br>
  <input id="height" type="number" value="100"> <br>
</body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
     var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
     var grid = 20;

 for (var i = 0; i < (800 / grid); i++) {
         canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid, 0, i * grid, 800], 
            {strokeDashArray: [3, 17], strokeWidth : 3, stroke: 'black', selectable: false }));
         canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * grid, 800, i * grid], 
            {strokeDashArray: [3, 17], strokeWidth :3, stroke: 'black', selectable: false }))
    }

 var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            top : 50,
            left : 50,
            width : 100,
            height : 100,
            fill : 'red',
            hasControls : false
        });

   canvas.add(rect);

   canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) { 
         options.target.set({
             left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * 
grid,
             top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
          });
        });

    canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
       var obj = e.target;
         // if object is too big ignore
        if(obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height || obj.currentWidth 
> obj.canvas.width){
            return;
        }        
        obj.setCoords();        
        // top-left  corner
        if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < 0 || 
 obj.getBoundingRect().left < 0){
            obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top- 
 obj.getBoundingRect().top);
             obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left- 
obj.getBoundingRect().left);
            }
        // bot-right corner
        if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height  > 
obj.canvas.height || 
     obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width  > 
obj.canvas.width){
            obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height- 
obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
            obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width- 
obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
        }
});
```

Comment: There is no Java in this example. Java != Javascript

Comment: @Gatusko why? All the code shown is javascript. You have tag edit ability yourself also

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry auto corrector!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are really asking two questions:

**1. How do I know when the value of a text box changes?**

You can find the input using `getElementById` and attach and event listener to the change `event`.

```
let widthInput = document.getElementById('width');

widthInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
});
```

**2. How do I resize an object in fabric.js**

You use the `set` method on the Fabric.js object. Then call `renderAll` on the canvas.

```
rect.set('width', parseInt(widthInput.value));
canvas.renderAll();
```

**All Together:**

*Note: You have to click out of the text box for the change event to fire.*

https://jsfiddle.net/9v5zogju/

HTML

*I removed in the invalid `type` attributes, gave each input a unique id, and removed the extra `body` tag.*

```
<input id="width" value="100"><br>
<input id="height" value="100"><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

Javascript

*I left your code as is. My code is at the bottom.*

```
     var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
     var grid = 20;

 for (var i = 0; i < (800 / grid); i++) {
         canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid, 0, i * grid, 800], 
            {strokeDashArray: [3, 17], strokeWidth : 3, stroke: 'black', selectable: false }));
         canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * grid, 800, i * grid], 
            {strokeDashArray: [3, 17], strokeWidth :3, stroke: 'black', selectable: false }))
        }

 var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            top : 50,
            left : 50,
            width : 100,
            height : 100,
            fill : 'red',
            hasControls : false
        });

   canvas.add(rect);

   canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) { 
         options.target.set({
             left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
             top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
          });
        });

        canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
        var obj = e.target;
         // if object is too big ignore
        if(obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height || obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width){
            return;
        }        
        obj.setCoords();        
        // top-left  corner
        if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < 0 || obj.getBoundingRect().left < 0){
            obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
            obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
        }
        // bot-right corner
        if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height  > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width  > obj.canvas.width){
            obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
            obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
        }
});

//new code below this line
let widthInput = document.getElementById('width');

widthInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    rect.set('width', parseInt(widthInput.value));
    canvas.renderAll();
});

let heightInput = document.getElementById('height');

heightInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => 
    rect.set('height', parseInt(heightInput.value));
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: You are a god amongst men, thank you. I changed the jsfiddle "heightInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
 rect.height = heightInput.value;
  canvas.renderAll();" to match the commands of the width input, due to it doing some pretty odd stuff otherwise. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/andrwrbnsn/doynL163/30/

After a quick look into it I hope this helps somewhat — fabric has setWidth and setHeight as can be explained here:

So essentially you use `document.GetElementById` to get the inputs and add an eventlistener which on `keyup` updates the width/height and refreshes the canvas.

[How do I change a value for a Fabric.js object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228676/how-do-i-change-a-value-for-a-fabric-js-object)

Comment: Thank you, the question you sent a link to is very useful. The jsfiddle is really handy for your use of the keyup.